# Java Spring MVC deploy .war on GlassFish

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, deployment, glassfish

At first i want to say that i'm a beginner in java servers and never deploy an java .war app on server other than localhost in my intellij.

I have a simple only REST app Which work fine in localhost, i also created war file and deploy it by command "asadmin deploy --port 4849 war_name", but when i go into url http://stachurskipiotr4.usermd.net/cookbook-1.0-SNAPSHOT there is an server error.

I completely don't know what it is, i will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Is someone (instructor, boss) requiring you to use an external container? If not, go with Spring Boot and let it handle all of that for you.

Comment: seems some libraries are missing from your war file. Can you try clean build and test again?

Comment: Did you try to access the default port 8080? Something like http://stachurskipiotr4.usermd.net:8080/cookbook-1.0-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

Access the domain port for that case. Default is 8080 if you haven't configured.

```
http://stachurskipiotr4.usermd.net:8080/cookbook-1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Also, please use or log in your admin console to see the apps if it's deployed. You can also access it directly from there.

Comment: port 8080 is not allowed in my hosting, a change it in configuration file by following the instructions https://wiki.mydevil.net/Java so my default port is 8081, but when i do asadmin deploy war_name.war i have an error "Remote server does not listen for requests on localhost:4848" so i use 4849

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish already provides the Jackson libraries and the version conflicts with the one Spring depends on. Glassfish is an enterprise container, is there a specific need for the enterprise container? Try a regular servlet container like Tomcat instead. If you do want enterprise, maybe you shouldn't need using Spring

EDIT:

Removing jackson jars from your project won't help you; Spring code wants the version it wants. You can try to find out which version Glassfish provides and then see which version of Spring depends on that and use that version of Spring. This is a wrong thing to try as this will be just the tip of the iceberg. Do not try to deploy Spring code in an enterprise container, these are competing specs.

Your options are

1) figure out why is Tomcat not working. Tomcat is a battle-tested servlet container with thousands of production deployments.

2) Try a different servlet container such as Jetty.

3) Rewrite your code to the JEE specification and deploy to an enterprise container such as Glassfish or Wildfly (there are others).

4) Use Spring Boot to embed the container and package your app as an executable jar.

EDIT2:

If you chose Spring Boot, your artifact will be an executable jar, you do not deploy it into a container since the container is embedded. You start the jar via a java command. You remove the container from your deployment entirely. I don't know your deployment environment, but you do not use Glassfish at all at this point, you have to run the java command to start the server.

If Glassfish is a requirement, you have to rewrite your code

Comment: Finally i installed tomcat, and sucessfull deploy .war application, now i try to deploy spring boot app in .jar, i do: "mvn clean install" and "mvn clean package" so i have a .jar file, i even run this in cmd by: "java -jar name.jar" and everything is ok, but when i upload .jar file in to /tomcat/webapp nothing happend, pleas tell me what am i doing wrong

Comment: You don't deploy the boot jar in tomcat, you just run it. You need to choose one: package war and deploy in tomcat or package jar with spring boot and deploy with the java command. Please pay attention to what I'm saying as this is the third time I'm repeating there same thing

Comment: I assuming that i just run: java -jar name.jar? I do that on port 8081 (set in applications.properties (server.port = 8081) and every thing seems to by ok, but i don't know what will be url to check thisf file is: demo1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and my domain is http://stachurskipiotr4.usermd.net/

Comment: Run the command on your own computer and point your browser to http://localhost:8081

Comment: I know i tried that before, but when i run this in my hosting it should be http://s13.mydevil.net:8081 but something doesn't work, i wrote mail to support